# Drupal 7 - Jquery in UTF8 not showing special chars

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, utf-8, special-characters

I am using drupal 7 with proper UTF8 encoding. I added some custom jquery/css script but i can't get special charachters as Š,Ž and Č to work, instead it returns [?] which is not very nice.

Im not sure what is wrong since my page header already includes the formatting utf8 following line but the problem is still there:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I also converted all the jquery files which im using to UTF8 without BOM format, using notepad ++ but it had no effect... Big thanks to everyone for all the answers, cheers.

Comment: Are you sure that ALL files you are using are in UTF8 no bom? Not just jquery fiels, but all template and module files?